# Care in creating codes to external sites

Tags: html, css

I am creating a small screen plugin that any user can implement on your website. It is similar to those chat rooms like Zopim and tawk.to, where the user takes a certain code javascript and paste on the website importing a box screen.

In my case, I am taking some precautions as:

- Creating divs with unlikely names of someone using `(id="____Plug___Box")`
- All the css of sub-divs, must first call the previous div and then the current div `#___Plug___Box #BoxInside`

But why am I doing this? because I have a little fear of an external CSS affect my plugin.

In my case I say to the user to implement my javascript code always in the bottom of the page (to stay away from that kind of thing), I'm doing the right way? Is there anything else I should implement in my code to prevent any interference of external CSS?

In the case of Zopim he seems to use css-inline, it would be a good thing?

Answer (score 1):

User always can overwrite your code. But you can provide random id prefix and create all elements from js side. Also using inline CSS will help.

```
var idPrefix = 'myPl'+(Math.rand() * 1000);

$('<div/>', {
    style: 'color: red;',
    id: idPrefix+'-wrapper',
    html: $('<span/>', {'class': idPrefix+'-header'})
});
```

---

I suggest using core classes for js manipulation and supporting classes for display that can be overwritten.

```
<span class="myPl-js-click-for-action myPl-css-color-red">Click this red text</span>
```